# How to edit content using Tiny Mce

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using Tiny MCE to edit some content within my site. I am having problems displaying text within the Tiny MCE content area ,which has been retrieved from the database.

What am I doing wrong? The text is plain not HTML formatted.

Thanks

Comment: Is the content from the database HTML? Is it getting encoded before being added to the `<textarea>` you're using?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to show using tinymce?

Comment: I have figured out what i was doing wrong. Thanx though for the quick responses ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either load the content inside the textarea before initializing tinymce or
update the editor's content after initialization. This can be done using: `tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('content');//setcontent needs to be called on the right editor instance`